# Angular js: How to use 'loop inside loop' in html tables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table

I have a json structure like

```
studentList = [
        {
            'name': 'name',
            'isNew': True,
            'class': 'class',
            'subjects': [
                {
                'name': 'subname',
                'mark': 70
                }, {
                'name': 'subname2',
                'mark': 80
                },
            ]
        },
        .....
    ]
```

I am trying to put this data inside an html table. The below code is not working for me.

```
<table>
 .....

<tbody>
    <div ng-repeat="student in student_list">
        <tr ng-class='{in:$first}'> New Student </tr>
        <div ng-if="student.isNew">
            <tr>
                <td> {{student.name}} </td>
                <td> {{student.class}} </td>
                <div ng-repeat="(key, subject) in student.subjects>
                    <td> {{subject.name}} </td>
                    <td> {{subject.mark}} </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </div>

        // Old student
        <tr ng-class='{in:$first}' > Old Student </tr>
        ....

    </div>
</tbody>
```

If I didn't use `<div>`, I can loop through the table. But for the above table structure, how can I represent data using angular.

Comment: your code structure is wrong, you can not write td inside div !! do you want 4 columns ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` element is not valid for a direct child of the `tbody` element. Just add the `ng-repeat` to the `tr` element.

If you need to repeat over 2 `tr` elements at once, you can use the `ng-repeat-start` directive:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="student in student_list">
    <!-- .. -->
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
    <!-- you still have the student object available here -->
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in angular directive "filter".
So on your ng-repeat you can have.

New students

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentList | filter : isNew">
<td>{{stuffgoeshere}}</td>
</tr>
```

Old students

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentList | filter !isNew">
<td>{{stuffgoeshere}}</td>
<tr>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your markup that are messing up your output.
You could do something like this. Unlike other html tags, table, tr,td, tbody tags are tightly grouped, you cannot have divs as child tags inside any of them.

Though it may seem work sometimes, but it is not something you should do. Always try to follow the nesting as table => tbody => tr => td => any tag.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.pro = [{
      product: "chicken",
      rating: 3
    }, {
      product: "fish",
      rating: 3
    }, {
      product: "pizza",
      rating: 4
    }];

    $scope.studentsList = [{
      'name': 'StudentName',
      'isNew': true,
      'class': 'class',
      'subjects': [{
        'name': 'subname',
        'mark': 70
      }, {
        'name': 'subname2',
        'mark': 80
      }, ]
    }, {
      'name': 'StudentNameOld',
      'isNew': false,
      'class': 'class',
      'subjects': [{
        'name': 'subname',
        'mark': 70
      }, {
        'name': 'subname2',
        'mark': 80
      }, ]
    }];

  }
]);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.header > td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <table>
      <tbody ng-repeat="student in studentsList">
        <tr ng-if="student.isNew" class="header">
          <td colspan="2">New Student</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="!student.isNew" class="header">
          <td colspan="2">Old Student</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="course in student.subjects">
          <td>{{course.name}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{course.mark}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```